# How to deal with MediaWiki questions

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, public-beta

While digging through [[mediawiki]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki) I noticed some questions which are about using some specific wiki (such as [Does the German Wiktionary have a way to request words to be added?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18438/does-the-german-wiktionary-have-a-way-to-request-words-to-be-added) which I don't think should be tagged `mediawiki` because it has nothing to do with the software) whilst most questions are more about configuring the software itself (like https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15682/mediawiki-deny-article-edit-right-to-all-users-except-admin-and-article-owner). This configuration issues clearly seem off-topic for me. Some seem borderline cases for me such as [How can I float the table of contents to the right with MediaWiki](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/how-can-i-float-the-table-of-contents-to-the-right-with-mediawiki) (if it should be on-topic it clearly deserves the `mediawiki` tag because it is a general question how to use the web interface of this software and may even help non-administrators in using it).

How should we deal with these questions?

Comment: don't hesitate to flag any specific situations like this and we'll follow up.

Answer (score 5):

I think we have to deal with them on a case by case basis.

I don't know what the right answers is for the specific questions are, but in general:

- If you see something badly tagged, retag it. If you don't have the reputation to suggest a new tag flag the question for a moderator to do it for you.
- If you see something that you think is off topic, vote to close. If you don't have enough reputation or you don't think enough people will see it before your vote decays flat it for a moderator to review.