# What is in common between [commons] and [mediawiki-commons]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

They have a lot in common, indeed they are about the exact same website:

- [commons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commons)
- [mediawiki-commons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki-commons)

Following common sense, we should merge them or make a synonym or other things we commonly do in such cases.

Comment: Please briefly describe what you found

Comment: @Rubén: Done, how is it now?

Comment: Related: [How to deal with MediaWiki questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/927/88163)

Comment: This sort of thing happens when people put spaces between words in a tag rather than a dash. So, someone put `wikimedia commons` instead of `wikimedia-commons`. `commons` is a terrible tag; it's not descriptive at all.

Comment: @ale: That's right! Feel free to post an answer suggesting a synonym or similar from `commons` to `wikimedia-commons`, or any better solution you might have.

Answer (score 1):

[mediawiki-commons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki-commons) at this time it has 0 (zero) questions, actually it is not listed on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags so just ignore it.

but....

[wikimedia-commons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia-commons) has 4 questions.

ale recently posted [Please rename [commons] to [wikimedia-commons]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4654/88163)

Comment: It had 3 questions yesterday. Thanks to the person who chose one tag and moved the questions that were using the other tag :-)

Comment: @nic maybe we was looking at the wrong tag :)

Comment: Oops, looks like I misspelled the tag actually :-O I will close my question as duplicate of ale's question.