# Please rename [commons] to [wikimedia-commons]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

*There's only 12 questions, and I'm tempted to retag them manually, but...*

[commons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commons) is too generic, and doesn't have meaning without the existence of other tags.

Since all of the questions with that tag are about Wikimedia Commons, [wikimedia-commons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia-commons) is a much better tag name.

Please rename, and possibly leave a synonym behind.

Comment: There are https://www.mediawiki.org/ and https://www.wikimedia.org/  (change of order of media and wiki) . The first is about a platform (software) the second about a movement (organization). Is this relevant for this request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All set.  Apologies that this got overlooked.

I did leave a synonym which can be removed if there's ever a product called "Commons" or the like.